# Why is a char* being treated the same as a char** in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, character-arrays

I have the following test application:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    char buf[512];
    buf[0]= 0x1;
    buf[1]= 0x2;
    char *temp1 = &buf;
    char *temp2 = buf;
    char *temp3 = &buf[0];
    printf("temp1:%p, temp2:%p, temp3:%p\n",temp1,temp2,temp3);
    printf("0 = %d, %d, %d\n",temp1[0],temp2[0],temp3[0]);
    printf("1 = %d, %d, %d\n",temp1[1],temp2[1],temp3[1]);
    return;
}
```

It compiles with a warning:

```
gcc ./testptr.c -o testptr
./testptr.c: In function ‘main’:
./testptr.c:9: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
```

But when I run it, all three pointers behave the same.

```
./testptr
temp1:0x7fff3a85f220, temp2:0x7fff3a85f220, temp3:0x7fff3a85f220
0 = 1, 1, 1
1 = 2, 2, 2
```

I know that `buf == &buf[0]`, but why does `&buf == &buf[0]`? Shouldn't `&buf` be a `char**`?

Comment: `&buf` is actually a `char(*)[512]` (a pointer to a 512-item `char` array).  They're not quite the same.

Comment: You changed your code between capturing the compiler output and pasting the code into the question.  The problem is on line 9 now.

Comment: Sorry you are right, just added a new line

Comment: An almost same question has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6472662/address-of-first-element-in-static-declaration-of-array

Comment: @Divij Thanks, good answers there too, hadn't come up in my search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All pointers behave the same because you declared all of them to be `char*`. C is statically typed so the type is bound to the variable and not the value.

Now that the behaviour part is explained, we only need to find out why they actually have the same value (as per the %p printf). Well, this is just an artifact of pointers being implemented as a memory address by GCC (the offsets and sizing that make a * differ from a ** are all handled by the type system/compiler behind the scenes). Do note that like any of the most suspicious stuff that gives out warnings, this is likely to be undefined behaviour or at the least, a bad practice :)

Answer (score 2):

Arrays are not pointers, although they can be used in much the same way. You happen to have found one aspect in which array and pointer semantics differ.

Comment: I discovered this when I had accidentally passed `&buf` instead of `buf` as the second argument of type `void *` to the [recv](http://linux.die.net/man/2/recv) function. Is it possible that this could cause a problem even though my example above does not illustrate it?

Comment: @austinmarton: I prefer to err on the side of paranoia when it comes to C compiler warnings

Comment: @missingno: Fair call. In my original application the mistake was passed as a void pointer so no warning was generated.

Answer (score 1):

You can work it out from the algebra of the `*` and `&` operators.

- we know that `buf` is the address of the 0-th element of the `buf` array
- we know that `&buf[0]` is also the address of the 0-th element
- by definition `buf[0]` is equivalent to `*(buf+0)`
- and `&(*(a))` is equivalent to `a`.

So, `&buf[0]` becomes `&(*(buf+0))` which is `buf`.

***Update***

Here, let's lay it out as a proof.

1. `&buf[0]`  Given.
2. `&(buf[0])` by C precedence rules with ()'s
3. `&((*(buf+0)))` because `buf[0] == *(buf+0)`.
4. `&(*(buf+0))` eliminating extraneous parens
5. `buf` QED

Comment: I agree with what you are saying (`buf == &buf[0]`), but that is not quite what I am asking about (`&buf == buf`?).

Comment: @austinmarton, follow the steps: they're a proof that, yes, `&buf` is equivalent to `buf`.

Comment: @Charlie: No, the proof says that `&buf[0]` is equivalent to `buf`, not that `&buf` is equivalent to `buf`, which was what the question was asking about.

Answer (score 1):

If you think about what code is actually being generated by the compiler when it processes an array, it becomes more clear.  The name buf references the address of the first (zeroth) element of the array (contiguous space for containing chars).  If you look in the object at the symbol table's entry for "buf", you'll find the address of that first element.  When you reference, e.g., buf[0], the compiler generates the address of buf, plus zero times the size of a char.  This happens to be the same as the address of buf itself.