GCC compiler handles "char * str" and "char str[]" with the & operator differently
The compiler treats the types char * var and char var[] differently when it comes to taking the address of a variable via the & operator. Here's a little snippet of code to demonstrate:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    const char * str1 = "This is string 1";
    char str2[32];
    snprintf(str2, sizeof(str2), "This is string 2");

    if ((uint32_t)str1 == (uint32_t)&str1) {
        printf("str1 == &str1\n");
    } else { printf("str1 != &str1\n"); }

    if ((uint32_t)str2 == (uint32_t)&str2) {
        printf("str2 == &str2\n");
    } else { printf("str2 != &str2\n"); }

    return 0;
}

The output:
iuser@MyXPS MINGW64 ~/Documents/pointers
$ ./run.sh 
str1 != &str1
str2 == &str2

Can someone please explain why the compiler refuses to get the address of a character array pointer?

Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6472662/address-of-first-element-in-static-declaration-of-array

Your program has undefined behavior so the result can't be predicted. Anything may happen. When converting pointers to unsigned integer use uintptr_t

Your use of snprintf to assign str2 rather than simple initialisation as you used for str1 suggests perhaps further misunderstanding.

In this declaration
const char * str1 = "This is string 1";

there are defined two things: the pointer str1 with automatic storage duration and the string literal "This is string 1" with static storage duration.
The pointer is initialized by the address of first character of the string literal.
So the expression str1 yields the address of the first character of the string literal while the expression &str1 yields the address of the variable str1 itself. Obviously they have different values.
In this declaration
char str2[32];

there is declared a character array. The address of the array itself as a whole object and the address of its first element are equal each other. Actually address of an array is the address of the extent of memory occupied by the array. So these expressions str2 and &str2 produces the same value (of different types).

This isn't a gcc thing, this is simply how arrays work in C.  When you declare an array like
T a[N]; // for any object type T

what you get in memory looks like
   +---+
a: |   | a[0]
   +---+
   |   | a[1]
   +---+
    ...
   +---+
   |   | a[N-1]
   +---+

That's it -- you get the sequence of array elements and nothing else.  There's no pointer to the first element or any other metadata.  Importantly, the address of the first element of the array is the same as the address of the entire array.
The array subscript operation a[i] is defined as *(a + i) -- given a starting address a, offset i elements (not bytes) and dereference the result.
But if an array isn't a pointer or doesn't store any pointer metadata, how does that work?
Like this -- under most circumstances, an expression of array type will "decay" to a pointer to its first element; basically, anywhere you use the expression str2 it will be converted to the equivalent of &str2[0].
One exception to this rule is when the array expression is the operand of the unary & operator; in that case the conversion doesn't happen and you get a pointer to the overall array.
But if the address of the array is the same as the address of the first element, what's the difference between &str2[0] and &str2?
The difference is in the type:
Expression    Type            Decays to
----------    ----            ---------
      str2    char [32]       char *
     &str2    char (*)[32]    n/a

If you have
char *p1 = str2;
char (*p2)[32] = &str2;

p1 + 1 yields a pointer to the next char object (str2[1]), where p2 + 1 yields a pointer to the next 32-element array of char.
